# Long-polling without looping

Tags: ajax, networking, websocket, long-polling

I'm new to computers in general and VERY new to web development specifically.

My question is about long-polling.

The unsophisticated way of keeping a connection alive using HTTP 1.0 is to have an ajax call keep looping over and over.

The more sophisticated way is to move the looping to the back end and have the server script only send an answer when necessary.

This is better as it does not stress the network so much, but it still requires unnecessary computer operations that stem from constant looping to check a condition.

The only difference between the two is where the looping occurs.

Both, however, seem hacky.

How do you establish a connection and only perform operations when a new change of state creates an interrupt somewhere?

I this what's called 'websockets'?

After all, this seems like the most sophisticated way of doing things, similar to the phone system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below if you want to use js only:

Catch is you have to open the connection every time unless you can keep your connection open at server side:

```
(function poll(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
        //Update your dashboard gauge
        salesGauge.setValue(data.value);

        //Setup the next poll recursively
        poll();
      }, dataType: "json"});
  }, 30000);
})();
```

With websocket you can implement the same like below:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect("http://localhost");
  socket.on('something', function (data) {

    //do something with data

    socket.emit('somethingelse', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand there might be some confusion regarding AJAX long pulling and the function of the Server vs. the Client in this situation.

Let's start at the beginning. Unlike Websocket connections and some HTTP streaming techniques, HTTP connections close when the client (browser) has finished downloading the data.

Only Clients (browsers) can initiate a network connection with a Server. Servers cannot initiate a connection.

This arrangement raises two issues:

1. There is no way for the server to contact a client and "push" new data after the network connection is closed.
2. This causes network slowdowns because of an important feature of network connections called 'slow start'.

AJAX attempts to address the first issue (updating old data) by opening new connections and "pulling" data.

Every so often, the browser would create a new connection, asking the server "what's up?". If new data exists, the server answers with the new data. Otherwise the server answers "nothing new".

Think of AJAX like a server's nagging wife. The "looping" is done using JavaScript on the Browser, which is the only one who can open new connections (so there is no background processes used by the server).

Websockets, on the other hand, and HTTP/2, address the issue of network application performance by attempting to avoid the repeated "slow-start" (re-using the same connections means that the connections are already running faster) and allow servers to "Push" data (eliminating excess traffic).

When you use Websockets, it's the Server's responsibility to push new data to the client and it's the client's (browser) responsibility to reconnect to the server if a connection is lost (which could and probably should normally happen to ensure network operability from time to time).

The server is required to keep track of the connections and send the right data to the right client.

This allows for higher performance and better use of network resources at the expense of server resources and programmer's work-hours. The trade is, in my view, well worth it. Websockets are amazing and together with HTTP/2 they should help us create amazing things and a superior user experience.

For an example of different JavaScript code used by the client (browser), you can read Rony's answer.